# Вопрос об учебниках по стилистике.

Tags: стилистика

Скажите, есть ли таковые? Что-либо, подробно рассматривающее тавтологию, плеоназм, ритмику текста и сходные вопросы.

Comment: Если же вам надо именно учебник, то практически в любом учебнике по стилистике, вы найдете ответы на интересующие вас вопросы.

Comment: спасибо, вам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Культура письменной речи. РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК - Плеоназм и тавтология](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=460.G1HSQijXrmBJUOSD24VLjCUc56Cv2ci9HMa6kB-XGvS1t9k4sxKzU2AsMWzEP04aM5Cit5_cNQte6TbkutUM0uzIYPIiWSMX8kVDkn9GRZCIC1JUUHMHN5VS12l24-hh.1727152956f597acb38c42ef5b1d981de2eecbea&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9Xuhyw5P1wAdC5B4OoApALaNwStX8ahkOrhQBZXPYKMiJCs6oHEVFeXPdenYp4dpmjGKVfw565RXwml83Fs4rqITDaOIXG8khYelnVIeRHFsb_QTu7JySQLd9kB5WnqHpvwYbFcQJiyGKkgtYkVQM4GP7r7zaEWaaergrYgRWRLE7Q&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxclhUVzM1eE1wbjBzNDlldVFOaC0zMzZ0Y1pJZ1llMUFUZkZSQUpNU3l5VUljQ3dBeDEwWEJTQVJvODFJX01NdC1jWUo3Ni10d1VYTnJMUnBXVDlIdjVLRmRHMGdIenZkOGhwd3U5TEI1a0E&b64e=2&sign=528b32a459a384c380662469284fbe80&keyno=0&l10n=ru&cts=1411911060341&mc=3.238901256602631)